# Ant FTP task uploading truncating files to multiple of 1024 bytes

Tags: ant, file-upload, ftp

I'm running an Ant target which contains this:

```
<ftp action="send"
    server="${ftp.server}"
    remotedir="${ftp.remotedir}"
    userid="${ftp.userid}"
    password="${ftp.password}"
    systemTypeKey="WINDOWS"
    binary="no"
    verbose="yes">
    <fileset dir="${dist.dir}">
        <includesfile name="${temp.dir}/changedListText.txt"/>
    </fileset>
</ftp>
```

"changedListText.txt" is a newline-delimited list of files to upload.  All text files I upload end up having a size of zero.  Also, all binary files I upload have a size that doesn't match my local machine's.  I thought splitting the text and binary files would help, but apparently it didn't.

I can find precious little documentation on the Ant FTP task, and as far as Verbose is reporting, there don't appear to be any errors during the upload.

**EDIT: I see now that it's only uploading whole chunks of 1024 bytes.  My text files are small, so they're ending up rounding down to zero.**

Comment: `binary="no"` allows the FTP protocol to modify your files in flight if the line-ending conventions of the server don't match the client. Seems like trouble to me, especially if you are uploading some files you've called `binary`. :)

Comment: Whether I have binary="no" or binary="yes" (default), my text files fail to upload and my binary files are the wrong size.  Seems like trouble to me too, but I'm at my wit's end trying to figure out what's going on!  lol

Comment: @Jonathan, hrm, that does smell like trouble. :/

Comment: Turns out that the files are only uploading full chunks of 1024 bytes...

Comment: Excellent discovery, sounds like a pain to find though. Any chance you can switch to `sftp` or something instead? :)

Comment: Don't think my host has any SSH exposed...  I'm a bit of a dummy when it comes to web protocols, though.  I'm running Vista 64, and I don't know what the host is.  The org.apache.commons.net FTP task, being written in Java, shouldn't have any issues running on a 64-bit system, right?

Comment: @Jonathan, I would expect it to work perfectly, but .. something obviously isn't. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your probably using *Apache Commons Net 3.0*. Change to *1.4.1* and it will work. Don't forget to remove the *3.0 jar*.

The jar file can be downloaded from: http://commons.apache.org/net/download_net.cgi

Comment: That's exactly the problem!  For what it's worth, I had to dig up an old version of Jakarta-oro as well.